# git SSL problems on corporate network

Tags: git, ssl, bitbucket

I am trying to checkout my git repository from Bitbucket. I do a checkout but this get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents$ git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (guestlogin.mycompany.com) does not match target host name 'bitbucket.org'
```

I read some other posts here and tried again with SSL verification disabled:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents$ git -c http.sslVerify=False clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I am afraid that some of the problem is that I am behind a corporate network. Is there anything that I can do on my side to resolve this?

**EDIT:**
What confuses me is that if I connect my phone to the corporate wifi, enable mobile hotspot on the phone, and then connect the computer (raspberry pi) to the mobile hotspot, the clone works fine. However, if I connect the raspberry pi directly to the corporate network (PEAP), I experience the SSL problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely caused by a proxy server sitting between you and Bitbucket. The directions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/can-t-clone-or-pull-due-to-a-git-outbound-proxy-779171769.html specifically mention Bitbucket Server (the self-hosted version, not bitbucket.org) but the proxy instructions should work for you regardless. If they don't, then talk to your company's network people and see what you can come up with together.

You may also be able to use SSH, if your corporate network permits that. I'd strongly advise against `http.sslVerify=False`, though - not only did it show you the exact problem (you're getting to an internal proxy server but not to Bitbucket) but it also protects you from many man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: What confuses me is that if I connect my phone to the corporate wifi, enable mobile hotspot on the phone, and then connect the computer (raspberry pi) to the mobile hotspot, the clone works fine. However, if I connect the raspberry pi directly to the corporate network (PEAP), I experience the SSL problems.

Comment: Are you connecting your phone to the corporate INTRAnet, or is it a guest wifi network that starts you off outside the firewall?

Comment: @Mort Both the phone and the computer with the git client are connected to the same guest network.